# Email Ping hangs on email

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, email-validation

I am trying to use a script I found to ping emails to ensure that they exist.

```
with open(input_list, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        address = row[0]
        person_name = row[1]+' '+row[2]
        company = row[4]
        match = re.match('^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$', address)
        print("Email for ", person_name)
        print(address)
        if match == None:
            synt = 'Bad Syntax'
            warnings.warn(address + " has bad syntax.")
        else:
            synt = 'Good syntax'
        dom = re.search("@(.*)$", address).group(1)
        print(dom)
        try:
            records = dns.resolver.query(dom, 'MX')
            mxRecord = records[0].exchange
            mxRecord = str(mxRecord)
        except:
            warnings.warn("Issue contacting domain")
            pass
        # Get local server hostname
        host = socket.gethostname()
        # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)#will need this for mail sending
        while True:
            try:
                server.set_debuglevel(0)
                # SMTP Conversation
                server.connect(mxRecord)
                server.helo(host)
                server.mail('me@domain.com')
                code, message = server.rcpt(str(address))
                server.quit()
                if code == 250:
                    print('Success')
                    new_row = [address, person_name, company, synt, 'Ping Successful']
                    email_data.append(new_row)
                    with open('cseresult2.csv', 'a+', newline='') as mess:
                        writ = csv.writer(mess, dialect='excel')
                        writ.writerow(email_data[-1])
                else:
                    print('Bad')
                    new_row = [address, person_name, company, synt, 'Ping Bounced']
                    email_data.append(new_row)
                    with open('cseresult2.csv', 'a+', newline='') as mess:
                        writ = csv.writer(mess, dialect='excel')
                        writ.writerow(email_data[-1])
            except:
                continue
            break
        print()
        print('================')
        print()
        time.sleep(3)
```

The code works mostly fine. However, with out the while loop, I get a lot of timeout errors:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

The while loop has taken care of that, but now it will hang on an email on not iterate through the rest of the list.  This is for a project, so any help to get it to move would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is set to continue forever if it encounters any kind of persistent error. You have a lot of code in the `try` block, so there are plenty of cases where this might happen (e.g. failure to connect to your email server, failure to open your csv file, etc.). Without more information I can’t say for sure this is happening, but it certainly wouldn’t hurt to address that.

Since the only error you are concerned with is `TimeoutError`, you should catch that error explicitly and `continue` only in that case. For all other errors, either print the error and break the loop or let the error bubble up. You should also set the timeout to a sane value when creating your server instance. And finally, you’d be better off with a `for` loop that ends if the timeout is not resolved after a certain amount of time; even in the case of a persistent `TimeoutError` you don’t want to try forever:

```
### Set a sane timeout
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587, timeout=1)

### Try a maximum of 10 times
for i in range(10):
    try:
        ### Connect to the email server and write to your file

    except TimeoutError, e:
        print e

    ### All other errors will bubble up
```

If you are curious what the default timeout is, you can do this:

```
import socket

print(socket.getdefaulttimeout())
```

The response is the default timeout, in seconds. A value of `None` indicates that you will never timeout, which doesn’t seem to be the case for you.